# Am I correctly punctuating this pause?

Tags: punctuation

I want to convey the pause between the "then" and the rest of the sentence. But I'm not sure a comma is the correct punctuation to use.

> Then, when the smoke had cleared Jane

Or is an ellipsis better? I tend to reserve it for when someone trails off or is interupted in the middle of speech.

> Then... when the smoke had cleared Jane

Are either of these correct or is there a better way to express this pause?

Comment: Not posted as a full answer because I don't have access to resources to validate it, but the comma is correct; the ellipses should be reserved for a dramatic puase, or more commonly for the trailing off of thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first comma isn't the problem. It's that you have an interrupter and didn't put the *second* comma in.

> Then, when the smoke had cleared, Jane rushed over to her.

An *interrupter* is a few words or a whole clause which interrupts the flow of the original framing sentence, and can be safely removed from the original sentence without making it grammatically uncorrect.

An interrupter *must* have bracketing punctuation. You can use commas, M-dashes, or parentheses, or in rare instances ellipses if you're careful.

If you take out the interrupter clause here, it just reads:

> Then Jane rushed over to her.

Other examples:

> Jane flung open the door, and — once the smoke had cleared and she wasn't in danger of choking — rushed over to her.
>
> Jane felt (now that it had been a few years) like she could go back to the city.